# How to properly use backed-up DBs for parachain recovery?

Tags: parachain, relay-chain

We are currently backing up our parachain DB on a daily base: `/path/to/db/full/`, I thought it can be used for recovery when the DB gets accidentally deleted/corrupted. But it seems that once the onchain state is newer than the backed-up DB, it can't be used anymore.

The steps that I've done:

1. Start a `2 relaychain + 1 parachain node network`, so this parachain node is the sole collator in this case
2. Assume the parachain runs to block #30, kill the parachain, make the backup (= copy the parachain-db folder to somewhere else)
3. Remove the parachain DB, restart parachain, the parachain will be stuck at #0 => `OK`
4. Stop parachain, replace the parachain DB with the backed-up one, restart parachain
5. Parachain will start from #30 and continues to produce blocks => `OK`
6. Wait until it runs to #40, stop parachain, remove the parachain DB (simulates that the DB gets accidentally deleted and we only have an older backup)
7. Restart parachain, it will be stuck at #0 => `OK`
8. Stop parachain, replace the parachain DB with the backed-up one, restart parachain
9. Parachain will be stuck at #30 and can't produce blocks anymore => `NOK`

So it looks like that an older backup can not be used for recovery. Did I understand it correctly? If so what's the point of backing up DBs? Just for faster syncing for a newly launched node?